# Create a nickname to substitute a string without $VARIABLE, in bash cli

Tags: bash, alias, variable

Is it possible to create nicknames for frequently used strings, without using the '$' in front of $variables?

The string can be fixed and does not need to change for the lifetime of the shell prompt.

I know there are bash $variables but I am looking for a solution without using the '$' in front of a $variable, so it is quicker to type.

I know there are aliases to shorten the whole command, but I do not want to shorten a command, I want to shorten only part of a command.

For example, I want to replace this:

```
$ ssh remote_server_1
$ scp remote_server_1
$ my_script.sh remote_server_1

$ ssh remote_server_2
$ scp remote_server_2
$ my_script.sh remote_server_2
```

with this:

```
$ aliasthingy r1="remote_server_1"
$ aliasthingy r2="remote_server_2"

$ ssh r1
$ scp r1
$ my_script.sh r1
$ another_script.sh r1

$ ssh r2
$ scp r2
$ my_script.sh r2
$ another_script.sh r2
```

without doing this:

```
$ export r1="build_server_r1"
$ export r2="build_server_r2"

$ ssh $r1
$ scp $r1
$ my_script.sh $r1
$ another_script.sh $r1

$ ssh $r2
$ scp $r2
$ my_script.sh $r2
$ another_script.sh $r2
```

The reason is, it is quicker to type without '$' in front of each  r1 r2 than $r1 $r2, so it would be great if I can drop the '$'

Comment: I can relate to this because I'm this lazy too, but c'mon -- you can type the `$`. Imagine how many `$`s you could have typed instead of this post.

Comment: In `Bash` at least `Aliases allow a string to be substituted for a word when it is used as the first word of a simple command` - so you'll have no no luck with aliases here.

Comment: ssh in particular allows you to create aliases for hosts and you can also create hostaliases with the $HOSTALIASES env-variable pointing at a user host file or with a globale /etc/host. That's all specific to hostnames, though.

Comment: use `alias` for this kind of stuff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the specific use case of SSH, aliases in [`~/.ssh/config`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5) are the way to go. This is the way to abbreviate a host parameter and a set of options to SSH. Not only do they not require a preceding `$`, but they won't be used in contexts that don't call for host names accessed over SSH, and they will be used in other contexts that call for host names accessed over SSH such as SSHFS, rsync, etc.

```
Host r1
HostName remote_server_1
UserName vassilis

Host r2
HostName remote_server_2
UserName vp

Host r2test
HostName remote_server_2
UserName guest
```

---

For other use cases where an alias on the command line is actually called for, zsh has global aliases, defined with [`alias -g`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-alias). Bash has no such thing.

```
alias -g r1=remote_server_1
ssh r1
```

The main problem with global aliases is that they will trigger anywhere, even where they don't make sense.

```
% echo r1
remote_server_1
```

But they won't trigger if they're part of a word, so `scp r1:/some/path .` won't work.

If you want something that works anywhere on the shell command line, define a variable, and type the `$`. If it's really hard to type on your keyboard, you could map it to a more accessible key. For example, to make `M-v` insert a `$`, put this in your `.bashrc`:

```
readline_insert () {
  READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}${1}${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT:}"
  ((READLINE_POINT += ${#1}))
}
bind -x '\ev: readline_insert \$'
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, in the specific case of your example where the values you want to store are hostnames, yes, you can. Just edit your `/etc/hosts` file and add these lines:

```
build_server_r1 r1
build_server_r2 r2
```

You can now run:

```
ssh r1
scp r1:/path/to/file .
```

Whether `my_script.sh r1` will work or not depends on your script. If you are trying to connect to the server, it will probably work. If you need `r1` to expand to the string `remote_server_1`, it won't.

Comment: Good suggestion, this is at least part of what I want to achieve.

Comment: The entries in /etc/hosts also need an IP address. I do not want to hard-code an IP address, in case the admin changes it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such mechanism. Aliases sort of do that but they don't work like variables. Variables expansion need to be marked with `$` (which is not a lot of typing).

Hostnames in particular, however, can be aliased in several ways:

1. via `/etc/host`

   ```
   $ip|$target_hostname $hostalias
   ```
2. via the user-level hostfile specified in `export HOSTALIASES=$the_hostfile`

   ```
   $hostalias $ip|$target_hostname
   ```
3. via `dns`
4. via  your ssh config file ('~/.ssh/config') (ssh-only):

   ```
   Host $hostalias
      HostName $target_hostname
   ```